# Is there a way to trigger a backend event when user leaves a channel in Laravel-Echo?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-echo

I'm new to laravel and laravel-echo, so excuse me if this is a dumb question, but is there a way to trigger an backend event when a user leaves a presence channel? 
With pusher, I can set a webhook for presence events, but is there anything similar for redis?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can trigger a presence channel 'onLoad' of a page. Example using Vue may be inside `created()` or `beforeCreate()` method. Otherwise, in jQuery, you may put it in 'ready' closure:

```
Echo.join('presence-event')
    .joining((user) => {
    ....
});
```

...will trigger joining presence channel, and then,

```
Echo.join('presence-event')
    .leaving((user) => {
    .....
});
```

...helps you check when someone leaves

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Altough this works for most of cases, it will not run the code for the last user in the channel.

Comment: Note: I'm trying to use this to update the user status (online/offline) in a chat, so the last user end up being online after the user leaves the page. To overcome this problem, I scheduled a command to check the channel's users every 1 minute, but having a observable event would be better. I'm trying to listen for redis events with Redis::psubscribe, but I haven't had any succees yet ( don't really know how to use redis ...). 

Note2: Sorry for the bad english XD

Comment: There is `.here(users)` method as well that be used to find see the users online. Otherwise, if the last user leaves, you may manually update the online/offline status.

Comment: @MoacirQueiroz did you find any solution?